# beamer+biblatex: change the \footnotemark style of \footcite

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footnotes

Is it possible to change the `\footnotemark` style created by `\footcite` (from biblatex) so that it looks more like a citation symbol?

[image: changing citation mark]

I want to keep my references as footnotes, but I would like them to look more like actual citations.

MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: clean: {files:[temp.aux, temp.bbl, temp.bib, temp.blg, temp.log, temp.nav, temp.out, temp.run.xml, temp.snm, temp.toc, temp-blx.bib]}

\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Bla bla bla \footcite{greenwade93} Ble ble ble \footcite{goossens93}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**NOTE 1:** There are many questions on tex.stackexchange.com about changing the style of the footnote style. This is about the footnotemark itself.

**NOTE 2:** I don't use footnotes for anything else, so I don't mind changing the footnotemark directly, ignoring whether it was created by footcite or not. I just could not find how to customize footnotemarks this way...

Comment: While it is certainly possible to change the style I wonder why you want to confuse your readers by going against the tradition. I would never expect a [1] to point to a footnote.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But on the other hand [1] is in many styles a traditional mark for a reference

Comment: I find using the regular footnote mark is also confusing because it is strange to see a footnote symbol and then see a reference below. I have just tried @samcarter's solution and the slides look more intuitive: the viewer knows that a paper reference is being used, and he can easily see that references are being shown in the bottom (and will be shown in the end as well, as usual).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you don't use footnotes for anything else, you can modify `\@makefnmark` (this is what `\insertfootnotemark` calls)

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: clean: {files:[temp.aux, temp.bbl, temp.bib, temp.blg, temp.log, temp.nav, temp.out, temp.run.xml, temp.snm, temp.toc, temp-blx.bib]}

\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{greenwade93,
        author  = "George D. Greenwade",
        title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
        year    = "1993",
        journal = "TUGBoat",
        volume  = "14",
        number  = "3",
        pages   = "342--351"
    }
    @book{goossens93,
        author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
        title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
        year      = "1993",
        publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
        address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}

\makeatletter
    \def\@makefnmark{\hbox{{{\usebeamercolor[fg]{footnote mark}\usebeamerfont*{footnote mark} [\@thefnmark]}}}}

    \def\@makefntext#1{%
        \def\insertfootnotetext{ #1}%
        \def\insertfootnotemark{\@makefnmark}%
        \usebeamertemplate***{footnote}}    
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        Bla bla bla \footcite{greenwade93} Ble ble ble \footcite{goossens93}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]