# Counter value is accessed incorrectly in custom command (Beamer)

Tags: beamer, macros, counters

I am trying to create a command for citations within Beamer slides.
For this, I am creating a citation count that is used to number the citations and to stack them.

I have two problems:

1. As you can see below, the value of the counter is the same within both citations (for the stacking part only) which results in the citations being written over each other
2. The little numbers I use to indicate citations in-text are a space away from the word. I could just use negative hspace to fix this but I think there is a right way to do this (that will work both when I do or do not leave a space before the command

   [image]

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[calc]{picture}

\newcounter{citecounter}[page]

\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{
    \addtocounter{citecounter}{1}
    \textsuperscript{\thecitecounter}
    \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{
        \put(0.95\paperwidth,0.07\paperheight + 12pt * {\value{citecounter}})
        {\makebox(0,0)[r]{\color{black!60!white!30!green}
{\tiny{\textsuperscript{\thecitecounter}\rmfamily{ #1 }}}}}}%}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{References}
    Mr. Smith \mycite{Mr. Smith, THEJOURNAL,{\bf 00}, 000000 (0000)} showed that Mrs. Smith \mycite{Mrs. Smith, THEJOURNAL,{\bf 00}, 000000 (0000)} showed that they were right.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

Comment: I am currently trying to figure out what went wrong with the MWE formatting. If you already know, please let me know or feel free to fix it yourself if you can. For now I can just say that the code will work only when the red one is replaced by "[1]"

Comment: As usual the value is not expanded timely. And even if it did, if there was an overlay of some sort it would count multiple times anyways. The point is references like that are frowned upon on a slide by the author. Just put a superscript number and be done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why so complicate? If you want to formate your references by hand, simply use footnotes.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=green}

\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{{{\usebeamercolor[fg]{footnote mark}\usebeamerfont*{footnote mark}$^\@thefnmark$}}}}

\def\@makefntext#1{%
    \def\insertfootnotetext{ #1}%
    \def\insertfootnotemark{\@makefnmark}%
\hfill \usebeamertemplate***{footnote}}    
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{References}
    Mr. Smith\footnote{\tiny Mr. Smith, THEJOURNAL,{\bf 00}, 000000 (0000)} showed that Mrs. Smith\footnote{\tiny Mrs. Smith, THEJOURNAL,{\bf 00}, 000000 (0000)} showed that they were right.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To get automatic references, maybe look e.g. into the `\footcite` command with `biblatex`.

Comment: Trying to use footcite, I get "I found no \citation commands---while reading file test.aux" when I use BibTex backend, or a footnote that only gives a number as: "\textsuperscript{1}1" when using biber

Comment: @Bananach see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308038/beamerbiblatex-change-the-footnotemark-style-of-footcite for an example of footcite

Comment: Thanks. For future reference: \usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=verbose]{biblatex}

Comment: @Bananach If you are using `biblatex` don't limit yourself and if possible use `backend=biber`.

Comment: Thanks, but for my thesis I found that biber made the compilation time 10 seconds longer, which killed me since I like to compile after every half sentence. Since then I use bibtex for everything. Also I currently do not need any biber features

Comment: @Bananach BTW some of your old questions have answers, which seem to solve the problem. Maybe consider accepting them of if they don't solve your problem, comment on them.