# Footnote positioning in Beamer

Tags: beamer, positioning, footnotes, logos

I have two logos in a presentation and I also have footnotes. The problem is that my footnotes collide with the logos.

I have tried to change the size of the footnotes and its positionning. I could change the size of the footnotes thanks to `\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{\hsize thesize}{}` but not the positionning. Do you know any way to position horizontally the footnotes?

Thank you much!

EDIT: Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{Test}
\begin{document}
\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{\hsize 8cm}{}
  \maketitle
  \logo{%
  \makebox[0.95\paperwidth]{%
  \includegraphics[height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{unicorn1.png}%
  \hfill%
  \includegraphics[height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{unicorn2.png}%
  }%
  }
\begin{frame}{Footnotes with logo}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\footnote{Class aptent
taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
Quisque eget facilisis ex. Mauris bibendum posuere justo sed finibus.
Sed tristique orci arcu, id consectetur elit gravida porta. Donec non
erat vulputate, faucibus ante vel, pulvinar lacus.}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{\hspace{20ex}}{}` will move the footnote text 20ex to the right. However you would then need to move the footnote rule (or remove it completely).

Comment: If the comment of @domenicocamasta does not solve your problem, van you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Done! Thank you. The problem with the approach of @domenicocamasta is that is only adds a horizontal space to the very first line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dirty, dirty, dirty! If you need this for more than one footnote, change the individual elements, e.g. the footnotemark and the footnotetext. How to do this see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/308040/36296

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{Test}
\begin{document}

    \setbeamertemplate{footnote}{
        \hspace*{1.7cm}%
        \raisebox{1.7cm}{\insertfootnotemark}
        \parbox[b][2cm]{7.5cm}{
            \insertfootnotetext%
        }%
    }
    \logo{%
        \makebox[0.95\paperwidth]{%
            \includegraphics[height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}%
            \hfill%
            \includegraphics[height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}%
        }%
    }
    \begin{frame}{Footnotes with logo}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\footnote{Class aptent  taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
            Quisque eget facilisis ex. Mauris bibendum posuere justo sed finibus.
            Sed tristique orci arcu, id consectetur elit gravida porta.}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]