# How to footcite in square bracket like [1] in beamer?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, citing, footnotes

I am trying to cite using square bracket in beamer.

This is what it currently looks like

[image]

Good, now is there a way to change it so it looks like:

[image]

or some variation of it? Much thanks

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

%Information to be included in the title page:
\title{Sample title}
\author{Anonymous}
\institute{ShareLaTeX}
\date{2014}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
This is a text in first frame \footcite{abramov_gordon_feldman_chavarga_2012}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

bib.bib:

```
@article{abramov_gordon_feldman_chavarga_2012,
title={Sex \& vision I: Spatio-temporal resolution},
volume={3},
DOI={10.1186/2042-6410-3-20},
number={1},
journal={Biology of Sex Differences},
author={Abramov, Israel and Gordon, James and Feldman, Olga and Chavarga, Alla},
year={2012},
pages={20}
}
```

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/308040/36296 help?

Comment: or this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386708/36296 ?