# Disable subscript in footcite for LaTeX Beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footcite

I wish to disable the superscript of `\footcite` when using LaTeX Beamer, preferably locally. Here is a minimal piece of code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[style=verbose,citestyle=authortitle-icomp]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

 \begin{frame}{Citation}

 \begin{itemize}
     \item Here is a citation in subscript\footcite{knuth:ct}
 \end{itemize}
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So how should the citation look instead? Should there be a normal number instead? No number? Should the number in the footnote also be changed?

Comment: Just a citation of the form [1], or the number is also fine, so that I can put the brackets around it myself. I wish to retain the property of footcite that it shows the citation in the footnote with a certain number.

Comment: Like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/308040/36296 ?

Comment: Yes this solves it!

Comment: @NguyễnCảnhDũng Please don't repost the same comment multiple times, this makes it look very much like spam